# Hook bash autocomplete based on argument

Tags: bash, git, autocomplete

I have the following alias for `git`

```
[alias]
    review = !git stash && git fetch origin $1 && (git branch -m $1 tmp-review-$1-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S) || :) && git checkout -b $1 origin/$1 && :
```

You can use it like `git review <branch-name>`

How can I hook the already existing autocomplete for branches to the `git review`

I am searching for something like:

```
__git_complete gr _git_branch
```

but to be done based on the argument -> `git review <tab>`

In general is there a way to hook a bash autocompletion based on a regex or just the string match?

---

### Solution

For `git` see the @Timir's response bellow.

```
# add completion handler for 'review' command
_git_review ()
{
    __git_complete_refs
}
```

An in general you can hook your own autocomplete and call the default one like:

```
_tralala ()
{
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

    if [ "$prev" = "test" ]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W 'ninja pizza' -- "$cur" ) )
    else
        _git
    fi
}

complete -F _tralala git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define the following function in `git-completion.bash` or `.bash_profile`.

```bash
# add completion handler for 'review' command
_git_review ()
{
    __git_complete_refs
}
```

And that'll give you `git review <tab>` autocompletion. If you're also looking for `git <tab>` autocompletion to include your alias(es), you'll also need the following in `git-completion.bash`:

```bash
# add hook for further expansions
_git_known_expansions () 
{
    # list aliases
    echo $(git config --name-only --get-regexp alias | sed 's/alias\.//g')
}

# modify command list to include expansions
__git_commands () {
    if test -n "${GIT_TESTING_COMMAND_COMPLETION:-}"
    then
        printf "%s" "${GIT_TESTING_COMMAND_COMPLETION}"
    else
        echo "$(git help -a|egrep '^  [a-zA-Z0-9]') $(_git_known_expansions)"
    fi
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this one goes to my dotfile :) Otherwise I've added a more generic solution in the question.